# how to properly authenticate Node.js app using activedirectory / ldapjs module?

Tags: node.js, active-directory, ldap

I need to authenticate my Node.js app against Active Directory.
I've found the following node module to do that:

```
https://github.com/gheeres/node-activedirectory
```

I'm using this free AD service:  `http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/`

My code looks like this:

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var config = { url: 'ldap://ldap.forumsys.com',
    baseDN: 'dc=forumsys,dc=com',
    username: 'tesla@forumsys.com',
    password: 'password' };
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);

var username = 'tesla';
var password = 'password';

ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {
    if (err) {
        console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
        return;
    }

    if (auth) {
        console.log('Authenticated!');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Authentication failed!');
    }
});
```

The error I'm getting is:   `ERROR: {"lde_message":"invalid DN","lde_dn":null}`

What can I do to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

```
var config = { url: 'ldap://ldap.forumsys.com',
    baseDN: 'dc=forumsys,dc=com',
    username: 'tesla@forumsys.com',
    password: 'password' };
ERROR: {"lde_message":"invalid DN","lde_dn":null}
```

At first glance the error seems to point that you're supposed to change those values in the config object to match your local environment/active directory.

Comment: this change did not make any difference

Comment: I didn't change anything, I was just pointing out the code you need to update.

Comment: This is what forumsys has as their example: Server: ldap.forumsys.com  
Port: 389

Bind DN: cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com
Bind Password: password

Answer (score 0):

Its a configuration issue; below is the working peice of code using node and activedirectory libirary and "ldap.forumsys.com"

```
var ActiveDirectory = require('activedirectory');
var config = { url: 'ldap://ldap.forumsys.com',
               bindDN: 'cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com',
               baseDN:'ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com',
               password: 'password' }
var ad = new ActiveDirectory(config);

var username = 'uid=gauss,dc=example,dc=com';
var password = 'password';
 
ad.authenticate(username, password, function(err, auth) {
  if (err) {
    console.log('ERROR: '+JSON.stringify(err));
    return;
  }
  
  if (auth) {
    console.log('Authenticated!');
  }
  else {
    console.log('Authentication failed!');
  }
});
```

Output:

```
Authenticated!
```